# Thinkpad P50s keyboard stop working with MATE 16.04

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, mate

When I opened my computer today, everything was fine. At some point, my keyboard just stopped working on the desktop. I can log in, but as soon as I get to the desktop, it stops working. all of the lights work well, and I can turn on the brightness, but neither restarting or using an earlier kernel is fixing the issue. I have a feeling that it has something to do with sticky keys, but I can't find anything about it in the settings.

Comment: write the next command: 

    dmesg | grep keyboard 

And paste the output here

Comment: yeah, so I can't press the enter key, so I can't really run commands.

Comment: Turn on On screen keyboard: Go to system settings --> Universal Access --> Typing Tab --> On sreen keyboard